# Are there supposed to be bounds on parameters in 2PL Item Response Theory models?

Tags: psychometrics, bounds, item-response-theory

Recently I've been studying Item Response Theory (IRT) and have come across some issues with the application side of it. I currently have a dataset of ~200 respondents x 7405 questions (quite abnormally large question-wise for IRT I know). When estimating the [2PL model](https://www.publichealth.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/item-response-theory) via JMLE, I'm seeing discrimination parameter values that are quite low (within 10^-3 range). Due to the slope-intercept formulation that I'm using in [Stata](https://www.stata.com/manuals/irt.pdf) (page 38), this causes the difficulty parameter to quickly blow-up all the way to values as small as -8000.

According to the book "Item Response Theory Parameter Estimation Techniques" on page 92, it is common practice to bound parameters exactly due to the issue I mentioned above; the example given is the very old program LOGIST. Looking at the original LOGIST paper, it seems that the program lets the user define the bounds rather than having set bounds. Reading some other works I don't see any clear indication on common bounds or how to determine them.

Given that IRT is heavily grounded in repeatability and statistical analysis, this is quite unexpected to me. For any IRT experts out there, how exactly are the bounds on the parameters determined?

Comment: Have you checked any item fit statistics? It may be that those items are problematic in other ways and causing the model to spit back these really unreasonable estimates. It sounds more like an issue with the maximum likelihood estimator since parameter estimates blowing up is a pretty common symptom of convergence or estimation issues

Comment: The issue has to do with the parameterization being in the 'classical' form, where as the discrimination parameters approach 0 the difficulty terms will tend to infinity (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169247/meaning-of-large-values-of-parameter-b-b-4-in-irt-theory/169264#169264). The solution would be to estimate the model with a slope-intercept form, which most modern software does these days to avoid issues like this.

Comment: I'm not an expert on classical IRT, but it's entirely possible that the discrimination parameter can actually be negative for some items, if it's the case that high-ability subjects actually score worse than low-ability subjects on that item. Bounding discrimination to be $>0$ is a way of telling your model that this shouldn't happen, but since it's estimating discrimination as close as possible to 0, maybe that assumption isn't justified.

Comment: @philchalmers actually the issue lies in both the classical and slope-intercept form, since you can recover the classical difficulties from the slope-intercept form.

Comment: @Billy There are some items with no respondents answering correctly which does cause problems for IRT, however, even after removing this the same problem still exists which leads me to believe that bounds are required (in the book I mentioned they mention discrim parameters going to 0 and problematic items in different locations to highlight that the problems don't need each other to occur)

Comment: @Eoinisonthejobmarket Yes it is quite possible that the discrim. parameter is below 0 which is one of the reasons I'm so concerned about the bounds. It doesn't seem like a reasonable assumption to bound the discrim to be above .8 for example, -inf to -.8 and .8 to inf however seems ok. However, it doesn't have any statistical grounding and seems to step outside of the framework of IRT.

Comment: What I meant is that if you're using the classical formulation then yes bounds to keep the discrimination away from 0 are required, which is why some software enforce this. If you're using the slope-intercept form though no boundaries are required, as a slope of 0 is perfectly fine and does not change the interpretation of the intercept. In this case though the transformation into the difficulty parameter would be +- infinity, which makes sense given that this parameter pertains to where the response curve inflects (which with a discrimination = slope = 0, it does not).

Comment: I suppose the greater question is why you believe the lack of an inflection point in a response curve is some type of issue related to software. If, in theory, and item does not correlate with the latent trait being measured then at the population level the slope/discrimination is equal to 0, the probably curve would be flat, and the difficulty parameter would be infinite. Programs like LOGIT impose constraints so that they don't crash, but you've avoided this issue already by using a better parameterization through `Stata`

Comment: @philchalmers Thank you for the responses. I take your point about the slope-intercept vs classical and why it isn't so much of a problem for the slope-intercept form. I suppose I mainly assume this is a software issue for the following reasons:

- The estimation procedures that I've worked with were written in Python by people that are not psychometric researchers (Variational IRT Mike Wu)  [the public code has a MLE or JMLE estimator]
- I don't have a good reason to think that any item in the dataset wouldn't be indicative of the latent traits.

Comment: I would also like to mention that I haven't used stata, I simply found their description of the parameterization I am using to be good. If that software does indeed use the same parameterization I would end up with the same results I believe. 

I would also like to mention the reason I'm using software not implemented in R by psychometrics experts is that the R implementations tend to use MMLE for estimation which doesn't work on my dataset due to its size and some problematic items.